# Can't download Django

Tags: python, django

So I have Python on my new Macbook Air and now I'm trying to download Django and having no luck.  I've tried "wget" and the link from the Django site, then I downloaded it and tried "python setup.py install".  In both cases I get invalid syntax.  I have Python 2.712.  I'd really appreciate any help!!

Thanks, Tom

Comment: Could you please paste the error you are getting

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate, [How to install Django](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=how%20to%20install%20django) returns 3,079 hits on SO.

Comment: just do-  pip install django

Comment: you would already have python installed on your macbook , first ensure python is there by typing 

`$ python` (on terminal)

then if so then make a virtualenv using the following link : http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-mac-os-x/

and then try installing using pip

`pip install django`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to install django is probably to use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). You should already have it installed since you're running a Python 2.7 version greater than 2.7.9.

The [latest official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip) read:

#### Installing an official release with pip

This is the recommended way to install Django.

1. Install pip. The easiest is to use the standalone pip installer. If your distribution already has pip installed, you might need to update it if it’s outdated. If it’s outdated, you’ll know because installation won’t work.
2. Take a look at virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper. These tools provide isolated Python environments, which are more practical than installing packages systemwide. They also allow installing packages without administrator privileges. The contributing tutorial walks through how to create a virtualenv on Python 3.
3. After you’ve created and activated a virtual environment, enter the command pip install Django at the shell prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for install django is that the django version is not match your python. From the notice of the Django official website and your python version, i think FOR python 2.7 the best django version is 1.8.X.

Here is the download link:
https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.8.17/tarball/

You can download this version, and try the installation again.
Please see the official docs as this link.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/install/#installing-official-release

Comment: OK, I downloaded version 1.8 and this is what I got: wget https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.8.17/tarball/
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    wget https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.8.17/tarball/
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You just open the link from your browser, it will be downloaded by itself.

OR you can open this link: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/   at the right section, you will find the download link.

Answer (score 0):

With MacOSX, you have to download `pip installer`, then you can download very easily `Django` from pip.

I put two possibilities, depending to `Python2` or `Python3` :

```
# if pip not installed
$ sudo easy_install pip

# show current pip version
$ pip --version

# upgrade pip
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then you have to download Django :

```
# Django version for Python2
$ pip install Django  

or

# Django version for Python3
$ pip3 install Django
```

You can check the Django version :

```
python -m django --version
```